undefined global lov2d not working in vs code
so i downloaded love2d and its in program files and added it to the environment variables and opened vs code and downloaded the extension of love2d support and i did everything like the video on youtube right and its still now working, it says undefined global love so if anyone can please help me and i found that someone said that you can drag the main.lua file in the love2d app and it should work but it doesnt work for me also so please help and thank you.





i tried everything other extensions and nothing works, i even downloaded it on my ither leptop and same problem and i my friend also has the same exact problem

I believe this is an issue with the extension. I get the same error. After disabling the extension the error is also gone.

It looks like Lua LSP doesn't have enabled love2d 3rd party workspace support, try to look at Lua LSP settings or contact extension authors

Also to run Love2D, you can just open command prompt and run love . (assuming you are in folder with main.lua), or drop folder containing main.lua onto love.exe

Yes, by default the lua language server does (no longer?) load love2d by default, it needs to be added. The process changed a bit recently with the introduction of an addon manager: https://luals.github.io/wiki/definition-files/

The lua language server (lls) doesn't require love by default so,
add this at every first line of any lua file that uses the love table.
also with the love support extension you can use alt+l in order to run the project your in.
local love = require("love")

